# Webcam is going into sleep mode

Tags: linux-mint, webcam

If I don't use my Logitech C170 USB webcam on Mint for a long time, it will go in sleep mode and will not respond when I use it again. But then if I reconnect the webcam to another USB port it starts working again. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to "Control Panel" -> "Device Manager"
2. Find which USB hub the camera is connected
3. Go to "Control Panel" -> "Power Manager"
4. Uncheck "Allow Windows to turn off"

Camera should remain connected.

Comment: Is it corresponding with latest Linux Mint?